# Why can't I get the provider package to listen to a change?

Tags: flutter, dart

So I'm writing a very simple app, just to learn a little bit more about the provider package in flutter. The app is this:

[App functionallity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20v8A.jpg)

When I write in mi TextField, the text bellow it should change and the title should remain unchanged, but I can't get it to listen the changes from changeText method. The code is

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<Data>(
      create: (context) => Data(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: MyText(),
          ),
          body: Container(
            child: Level1(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Level1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Level2(),
    );
  }
}

class Level2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          MyTextField(),
          Level3(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Level3 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(Provider.of<Data>(context, listen: false).data);
  }
}

class MyText extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(context.watch<Data>().data);
  }
}

class MyTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      onChanged: (newText) {
        Provider.of<Data>(context).changeText(newText);
        print(newText);
      },
    );
  }
}

class Data extends ChangeNotifier {
  String data = 'Hello';

  void changeText(String newString) {
    data = newString;
    print('Hello $data');
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: I think it's because ` listen: false` .` listen: false` should be used in button press.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the TextField widget inside a Stateful widget.

```
    return TextField(
      onChanged: (newText) {
        Provider.of<Data>(context).changeText(newText);
        print(newText);
      },
    );
```

Enclose this in a stateful widget

Also you have to add a Text controller to the textfield widget, go to docs for textfield widget in flutter.

Comment: I've tried that already, but nothing changes :(. I even tried adding a setState() int he onChanged, you know because I didn't know what to do, but it doesn't work either

Comment: Why are you converting each widget to seperate widgets why can't you write it under one single stateless widget?

Comment: It's just an example to learn about the provider package, and I need to request information on different levels of my app. I need to understand it so I can use it in a much more complex app

Comment: oh ok, Try using textediting controller. Just google it

Comment: Tried that and didn't work either :(

```
class MyTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyTextFieldState createState() => _MyTextFieldState();
}

class _MyTextFieldState extends State<MyTextField> {
  TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      controller: _controller,
      onChanged: (newText) {
        print(newText);
        Provider.of<Data>(context).changeText(newText);
      },
    );
  }
}
```